# ScrewTurn Wiki positive permissions

Tags: wiki, screwturn

As I understand it, Screwturn wiki's permission style is inherently negative--if a user is a member of different groups, negative permissions (deny access) take precedence over positive permissions (allow access).  If I have a number of groups and I want to restrict access on some pages or a namespace to just one group, is there any way to do that without specifically denying access to all other groups?  That would run into issues because users could belong to a number of groups.  (I'm trying to use it for a knowledgebase in a corporate environment.)